# Factor effecting the size of .so libarary

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I m creating a library in .so format. after making many changes my library size has been increased by some amount. Is there any way/method to figure out why my .so size is changing.

Is there any points why which i can calculate the of my .so 
something like (class size,compiler, variables, static function ).. etc..

Comment: your library size will increase if you added some code in source. same as binary file it increase as you increase code.try compile it with `-Os` flag

Comment: @JKB can we ruffly calcualate the size of a .so with the classes. any relation with class size

Comment: Try `nm -gC yourLib.so`

Comment: So you want to know how size of lib is modified when you modified source right?

Comment: you can get .so file for only your class by `g++ -fPIC -shared myclass.cc -o myclass.so`

Comment: Why do you need to know?  Are you having problems fitting it on a CD or zipping or posting it?  You can spend a lot of time doing this: would you gain anything from it other than just knowing?

Comment: @cup you are right why should we bother about how class,functions and many things bind to .so file